# I want a redirect code in a frame to open the link in the entire window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to implement this HTML code, which is currently located in a frame

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.sungotanning.com/bookingpagehtml">
```

I am trying to use this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=http://www.sungotanning.com/bookingpagehtml" target="parent">
```

without success, how can I make the link open in the entire window? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => window.top.location.href="http://www.sungotanning.com/bookingpagehtml", 3000)` ???

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be the use of javascript. An iframe should not be able to change the containing page or redirect this page. So even Javascript might not work. Try to find a different way of doing this.

Comment: if the parent page is in the same domain, then there shouldn't be an issue, or if there is, it's easily overcome as the parent and iframe in the same domain can easily *communicate* and *cooperate* with properly written javascript

Comment: I've been successful in doing this in the past using only HTML and Javascript, unfortunately it requires the user to click a button in the frame. I am trying to get this to redirect automatically. Here is the code that will allow a button in the frame to open in the entire window.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5vd0kG

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following target="_parent"
Reference: http://html.com/attributes/a-target/